# Setting up a virtual host in Webmin

Tags: virtual, host, webmin

I set up a virtual host in a Linux server running Webmin 1.580. I gave it a server name and a document root directory. How do I access the website under the virtual host from the internet?

Am I supposed to type the server's IP address and then the name? That's not working. It says:

Error - File not found

Is there anything else I need to do to make my site live on the server?

Comment: Do you have DNS entries already populated to give users a way to map the name to the address?

Comment: Not sure, how do I go about setting those up?

Comment: Are you doing the hosting? Or are you using a hosting provider? many hosting providers make it easy to modify your DNS. Otherwise you may need to learn about [zone files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file). Or, if this is just something to be used on one or two workstations, you could hack it into the `/etc/hosts` file -- but that does not scale well beyond toys.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. It's our own server and I checked, we don't have the BINDDNS module on Webmin. I guess I need to get our server administrator to help me with that. I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using Virtualmin, in addition to Webmin, if you're going to be doing web hosting with the system. It makes most elements of the process a lot easier. The installation script will install all of the additional software you need (like BIND), and provides a friendlier GUI for web hosting tasks.

You can download it here: http://www.virtualmin.com/download

It is available in a free Open Source version, and is developed by the same people as Webmin.